# Difference between two recursive algorithms to delete a binary search tree

Tags: c, binary-search-tree

I have a question about these two algorithms:

This works normally:

```
node* deleteTree(node* root)
{
    if(root != NULL)
    {
       deleteTree(root->left);
       deleteTree(root->right);
       deallocateNode(root);
    }
    return root=NULL;
}
```

This nope:

```
void deleteTree(node* root)
{
   if(root != NULL)
   {
      deleteTree(root->left);
      deleteTree(root->right);
      deallocateNode(root);
   }
   root=NULL;
}
```

Why? I need to set the `root` to `null` so the node pointer after the delete of the BST will not point to a memory not allocated.
I prefer the second algorithm because the recall of the function is more intuitive.

Theoretically, the two algorithms are equivalent but if I use the second algorithm and I try to print the BST, the program goes in a loop.

Comment: I like the function names, they are clear in what they are trying to do, but the check does not make sense to me if (root != NULL)... else ... root = NULL; assigning null to something which is already null. That part I don't understand.

Comment: In the second you just set the local pointer object's value to NULL. If you meant to update the original pointer, you need to take a pointer to pointer to node, and update `*root = NULL`. I assume that with the 1st you call it like `root = deleteTree(root)`, and since it returns NULL, your original is set to NULL. One would not have to speculate, if you'd provide *complete* examples.

Comment: You should do a quick internet search about C functions with the keywords "Call by value" and "Call by reference".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have `node *root` and assign `node = NULL` it won't affect its value in exterior. If you want to modify the pointer value, you'll have to pass a double pointer.

Something like:

```
void deleteTree(node** root)
{
   if(*root != NULL)
   {
      deleteTree(&((*root)->left));
      deleteTree(&((*root)->right));
      deallocateNode(*root);
   }
   *root = NULL;
}
```

But I don't really think you need to assign `node = NULL` since you free it. So, you can just assign `node = NULL` after you call deleteTree and you won't need to mess with double pointer.

Comment: might be better to declare `node *n = *root` than to use combinations of `*` and `&`.

Comment: In fact that was may first idea. I dont'want to use double pointer and i can't  set out of the function root to NULL  so the only way is to use a function that returns the node pointer?